# Dalvik bytecode tracer

Tags: android, runtime, bytecode, dalvik

How can I get the trace of dalvik bytecode that is being executed while the device is running an app (like logcat does)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no existing tool to do what you want, but it might be possible to implement such a tool without too much work.

The general idea is that you want to connect to dalvik's vm as a debugger, using the jdwp protocol, and single step the virtual machine, inspecting the state between each step and printing out the instruction. You should be able to get the... instruction index. Or maybe the instruction offset, via JDWP.

Additionally, you will need to read the dex file, and look up the exact instruction being executed, based on the instruction index/offset you get from JDWP.

You should be able to use [AndBug](https://github.com/swdunlop/AndBug) to implement the first part of the above solution, and then use [dexlib](https://code.google.com/p/smali/source/browse/#git/dexlib) to access the dex file, in order to get the instruction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will have a look on what you suggested.

Comment: FWIW, it's actually possible to have Dalvik log every instruction it executes by defining `LOG_INSTR` and running the portable interpreter (-Xint:portable).  See e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/mterp/out/InterpC-portable.cpp .  This adds so much overhead, and generates so much output, that nobody in their right mind would actually use it. :-)  (It was helpful in the very early days... might not even compile anymore.)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [`traceview`](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)

Comment: I already used traceview, that is not what i'm looking for. I need something like logcat that instead of the log, displays the dalvik bytecode that is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

It is realy too slow to trace the method not to speak the byte code,when you want to know what the app is doing the best way is to trace method first,then trace the byte code in it.